# Sterling serialization problem on Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, sterling-db

I have a problem with Sterling Database for Windows Phone. I implemented the database step by step in my wp7app, but it doesn't serialize my data when new entities are saved. For example: I serialize credentials using sterling database:

```
        var userCredentials = new UserCredentials(userName, password);
        App.Database.Save(userCredentials);
        App.Database.Flush();
```

But when the application is reactivated (or re-launched) Sterling doesn't return any values from isolated storage:

```
var firstOrDefault = App.Database.Query<UserCredentials, string>()
            .ToList()
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

My ActivateEngine method looks are standard and TableDefinition is:

`CreateTableDefinition< UserCredentials, string >(t => t.UserName),`

Why is sterling database doesn't serialize my data? Everything seems to be implemented fine. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you activating and registering the database on startup and diposing on completion as described in the [Quickstart](http://www.sterlingdatabase.com/sterling-user-guide/getting-started)?

My personal preference is to use an application service similar to the following:

```
namespace MyApp.Data
{
    using System.Windows;
    using Wintellect.Sterling;
    using Wintellect.Sterling.IsolatedStorage;

    /// 
    /// Defines a an application service that supports the Sterling database.
    /// 
    public class SterlingDatabaseService : IApplicationService, IApplicationLifetimeAware
    {
        public static SterlingDatabaseService Current { get; private set; }

        public ISterlingDatabaseInstance Database { get; private set; }

        private SterlingEngine _engine;

        /// 
        /// Called by an application in order to initialize the application extension service.
        /// 
        /// Provides information about the application state.
        public void StartService(ApplicationServiceContext context)
        {
            Current = this;
            _engine = new SterlingEngine();
        }

        /// 
        /// Called by an application in order to stop the application extension service.
        /// 
        public void StopService()
        {
            _engine = null;
        }

        /// 
        /// Called by an application immediately before the  event occurs.
        /// 
        public void Starting()
        {
            _engine.Activate();
            Database = _engine
                .SterlingDatabase
                .RegisterDatabase(new IsolatedStorageDriver());
        }

        /// 
        /// Called by an application immediately after the  event occurs.
        /// 
        public void Started()
        {
            return;
        }

        /// 
        /// Called by an application immediately before the  event occurs.
        /// 
        public void Exiting()
        {
            _engine.Dispose();
        }

        /// 
        /// Called by an application immediately after the  event occurs.
        /// 
        public void Exited()
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

If you use this approach, don't forget to add an instance in App.xaml:

```
    <Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
        <!-- Required object that handles lifetime events for the application. -->
        <shell:PhoneApplicationService Activated="Application_Activated"
                                       Closing="Application_Closing"
                                       Deactivated="Application_Deactivated"
                                       Launching="Application_Launching" />
        <data:SterlingDatabaseService />
    </Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
```

Comment: Thank you for your post Derek,
It helped me a lot. I noticed that when I was registering datatable, I didn't specified, that I want to use IsolatedStorageDriver. I fixed it it with this line:

<code> _database = _engine.SterlingDatabase.RegisterDatabase< MyDatabase >(new IsolatedStorageDriver());</code>

thank you very much!